# Add export definitions for multiple files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My goal is to add typings to an existing JS project for intellisense (Visual Studio Code). There are several files (one for each "command") that all need to export the same things.

These types are intended to stay separate (only appear in code comments and external files). I have a definitions file for this. Each command file references this same definition file.

But looking at the result, none of the type information (that is not implied by the code) is being picked up in the source file. Is this the proper way to do this and what is being done wrong?

A command:

```js
/// <reference path="../cmd.d.ts" />

export const cmd = new SlashCommandBuilder();

// Does not say what pnone was supposed to return
export const perms = pnone()

// Does not know what interactions is or the return type
export async function execute(interaction) {
    
}
```

The definition (cmd.d.ts):

```js
export const cmd: SlashCommandBuilder

export const perms: (interaction: Interaction) => boolean

export async function execute(interaction: Interaction): Promise<void>
```

Comment: You might have to follow the patterns discussed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html#reference-example) around naming conventions and directory structure to get things to work correctly.